Why does gcc keep failing to build within MXE for Apple Silicon?
I used this command to initiate the build after cloning the mxe git:
make gcc MXE_TARGETS=x86_64-w64-mingw32.static

It ran smoothly, until it hit this error:
[build]       gcc                    x86_64-w64-mingw32.static

Failed to build package gcc for target x86_64-w64-mingw32.static!
------------------------------------------------------------
make[3]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make[3]: *** [lto-dump] Error 1
make[3]: *** [f951] Error 1
rm gfortran.pod gcc.pod
make[2]: *** [all-gcc] Error 2
make[1]: *** [build-only-gcc_x86_64-w64-mingw32.static] Error 2
real    1m53.069s
user    1m54.982s
sys 1m14.915s
------------------------------------------------------------
[log]      /Users/[user]/mxe/log/gcc_x86_64-w64-mingw32.static

make: *** [/Users/[user]/mxe/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static/installed/gcc] Error 1

I disregarded the error and ran the make command again, and then it gave me this error:
[build]       gcc                    x86_64-w64-mingw32.static

Failed to build package gcc for target x86_64-w64-mingw32.static!
------------------------------------------------------------
config.status: executing default commands
config.status: creating Makefile
config.status: creating testsuite/Makefile
config.status: creating config.h
config.status: executing default commands
make[1]: *** [build-only-gcc_x86_64-w64-mingw32.static] Error 2
real    0m52.300s
user    0m35.289s
sys 0m35.757s
------------------------------------------------------------
[log]      /Users/[user]/mxe/log/gcc_x86_64-w64-mingw32.static

make: *** [/Users/[user]/mxe/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static/installed/gcc] Error 1

I've tried running make clear and restarting the terminal, but to no avail.
